# How to use same component in normal way and with angular material dialog both?

Tags: angular

I have a component which I'm trying to use from 2 places

1. Normally, including the selector in some template for example `<comp-a></comp-a>`.
2. Inside of angular material dialog.

When using the same component with angular material dialog, I have to inject the below dependencies

```
  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<CTConfigurationComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public dialogData: any,
  ) {}
```

It is working fine with case 2, but case 1 is breaking with below error
[image]

Tried using `@Optional()`, `@Skip()` but no success.

**Question -1 :**
1. Is it possible to tell angular DI to skip few dependencies?

Tried `public injector: @Injector`, and in constructor calling

```
this.dialogRef = this.injector.get(MatDialogRef<CTConfigurationComponent>);
```

is also not working.

---

**EDIT-1:**

```
(method) Injector.get(token: any, notFoundValue?: any)
```

**Question - 2:**

### Is there any similar thing like `notFoundValue` of `Injector.get` when we are doing DI through constructor?

Any suggestion or explanation will be helpful

Comment: When you use `MatDialogRef`, does your html also contain `<CTConfigurationComponent></CTConfigurationComponent>` ?.

Comment: No, I am using the component selector in one workflow and in another, I am opening this component inside of angular material. as `const dialogRef = this.matDialog.open(CTConfigurationComponent, {
      minWidth: '320px',
      maxWidth: '450px',
      disableClose: true,
      panelClass: 'consent-banner-panel-class',
      backdropClass: 'backdrop-class-dark8',
      data: {}
    });`

Comment: can you post your `app.module.ts` code?

Comment: Actually, the configuration component is featured module so it has nothing to do with app.module.

Comment: `@NgModule({
  declarations: [CTOnboardingComponent, CTConfigurationComponent, VerifyDomainComponent],
  exports: [CTConfigurationComponent, VerifyDomainComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CTAngularImportsModule,
    CTOnboardingRoutingModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [CTConfigurationComponent, VerifyDomainComponent],
  providers: [CTOnboardingService]
})
export class CTOnboardingModule {}`

Comment: it would be great if you add your code inside your question instead of posting in comments. It will be easier to read and understand :)

Answer (score 21):

After trying lots of things, I have got a workaround for this error. Posting the solution here so that it may be helpful to someone else

so instead of this

```
  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<CTConfigurationComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public dialogData: any
  ) {}
```

I am using below code

```
  private dialogRef = null;
  private  dialogData;
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
      this.dialogRef = this.injector.get(MatDialogRef, null);
      this.dialogData = this.injector.get(MAT_DIALOG_DATA, null);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your **app.module.ts**, you need to import the `MatDialogModule` and then add it in your `imports` property

**app.module.ts**

```
import {MatDialogModule} from "@angular/material";

@NgModule({ 
  declarations: [CTOnboardingComponent, CTConfigurationComponent, VerifyDomainComponent],
  exports: [CTConfigurationComponent, VerifyDomainComponent],
  imports: [ CommonModule, MatDialogModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, CTAngularImportsModule, CTOnboardingRoutingModule ],
  entryComponents: [CTConfigurationComponent, VerifyDomainComponent],
  providers: [CTOnboardingService] })

export class CTOnboardingModule {}
```

Comment: MatDialogModule is already imported into inside `CTAngularImportsModule `